# Using local storage to set values in a view MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a program that acts sort of like a wizard, so it goes from Page 1, click next, page 2, click next, page 3, etc...on button clicks I am using javascript to put certain checkbox control values into localstorage.  My problem is, when I press back to go to a previous page the control values are reset to 0/false.  How can I make a pageload type effect in MVC to refill these values from local storage.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC. When you use local storage, you're responsible for managing the stored data. If you want the fields, repopulated, you'll need to use JavaScript to read back the stored values from local storage and fill in the fields with those values.

Comment: It's really important to say why you want this.  Is this something that someone will do, walk away from, and then login from another computer?  If so then Local Storage is not the answer.  If this is something that is thrown away and has no persistence if the user does not finish it in the same session the local storage could work.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I understand that.  Where do you make that call though to "refill" those fields...I don't really want to make any calls on my view, as I understand it the view should be very "stupid".  I have Javascript routing which page I need to go, via the back/next button clicks, but once that redirect takes place...how do i trigger this refilling process?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use DIVs that are hidden:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div id="step1">
        <!--form objects-->
        <input type="button" id="to_step2_button" />
    </div>
    <div id="step2" style="display: none;">
        <!--form objects-->
        <input type="button" id="to_step1_button" value="Back" />
        <input type="button" id="to_step3_button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="step3" style="display: none;">
        <!--form objects-->
        <input type="button" id="to_step2_button" value="Back" />
        <input type="submit" id="finish_button" value="Finish" />
    </div>
}
```

And use jquery/javascript hide/show the DIVs depending on the step.

This method has other benefits such as: you can use 1 page, 1 model, 1 form, no reloading needed.

*Anecdote:* I worked on a property rental website, and the listing form had 87 fields that were grouped, and each group had a tab in a tabbed view (which were just hiding and showing divs within the form). And we added Next and Previous buttons which cycled through the tabs. It worked really well, made sense to the client, and we didn't have to mess around with trying to maintain form field states between pages. Everybody won.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to put JavaScript directly on my View that references my JavaScript file.  I put what I called LoadPage() method in the @Javascript section at the top of my page...Inside the LoadPage() I had code that looked like this:

```
function loadPage(currentPage) {

    var currentPage = currentPage;

    if (window.localStorage.getItem("chkProvider") == 'true') {
        document.getElementById('chkProvider').checked = true;
    }
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("chkSubscriber") == 'true') {
        document.getElementById('chkSubscriber').checked = true;
    }
}
```

This runs when the page loads and sets the values that I need updated.  This is an example of how one might update their View using JavaScript and local storage.  I hope my solution helps someone!